# Undefined variable in blade view (single valued data)

Tags: laravel, undefined-variable

I'm trying to pass variable `$cMonth` to my view. I tried looping it using `foreach` even if its a single valued data and error still says undefined variable .. I tried `dd($cMonth)` and the correct output is shown.

This is a snippet of my controller.

```
$cMonth = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1));

return view('admin.request',compact('showData','cMonth', 'year'));
```

In view, I am calling cMonth like this --

```
{{ ($cMonth) }}
```

Comment: It's a bit of a guess without the whole context. Are you setting `$cMonth` inside of an `if` statement or other loop/conditional? Try sharing your entire controller and view code. Also, you don't need the parentheses around the variable when displaying it. `{{ $cMonth }}` is just fine.

Comment: hello, have you tried reassuring that you have coded the `{{ ($cMonth) }}` in the proper blade view file? I mean you're trying to access the view `admin.request`, kindly double check if you have placed that code inside this blade file

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I am sure that its in the proper blade file..And I removed the parenthesis in cMonth and the error still shows. No its not in a loop or if statement. I just want to get the value of cMonth..

Comment: @wpd_monk, what is the error message you get when you're trying to display `{{ $cMonth }}`?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't post my view file. But I did get an idea of my error thanks to JueViole17 .. It is pointing to the right blade file. but the index function does not pass $cMonth to my blade because it wasn't declared there .. etc. etc. Thank you for the help. I'm not getting the error anymore..

Answer (score 0):

With this route code

```
Route::get('/test', function() {
    $month = 3;
    $showData = true;
    $year = 2019;
    $cMonth = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1));
    return view('test', compact('cMonth', 'showData', 'year'));
});
```

And this view

```
{{ $cMonth }}
```

It works as expected.
Have you tried using just that code for the view and see if it works?

You should post your complete view code, because it seems that somewhere/somehow the variable get unset.